# In tensorflow, how does one access a scalar tensor value before it is moved to the GPU?

Tags: tensorflow

In tensorflow I register an op like so:

```
REGISTER_OP("RimeBSqrt")
    .Input("stokes: FT")
    .Input("alpha: FT")
    .Input("frequency: FT")
    .Input("ref_freq: FT")
    .Output("b_sqrt: CT")
    .Attr("FT: {float, double} = DT_FLOAT")
    .Attr("CT: {complex64, complex128} = DT_COMPLEX64");
```

All of the above inputs are tensors,
but ref_freq is a scalar or 0-D tensor.
In the Compute() method of my CPU kernel
I can do the following to extract the scalar:

```
const Tensor & in_ref_freq = context->input(3);
FT ref_freq = in_ref_freq.tensor<FT, 1>()(0);
```

However, the same kind of code generates a segfault
in the Compute() method of my GPU kernel, because
the CPU now tries to access a block of memory on the
GPU device. Is there anyway to intercept this scalar
value before sending it into the GPU? I'd like to avoid
the following extra level of memory indirection in
a CUDA kernel:

```
template <typename FT>
__global__ void kernel(..., FT * ref_freq, ...)
{
    FT value = ref_freq[0];
}
```

I don't think `Attr` is the approach to use for `ref_freq` since it is changeable, configurable value.

1. CPU Tensorflow kernel code is [here](https://github.com/ska-sa/montblanc/blob/53edf2ba505e4b5b10ae89e187c4f11d1e7072db/montblanc/tensorflow/rime_ops/b_sqrt_op_cpu.h#L71).
2. GPU Tensorflow kernel code is [here](https://github.com/ska-sa/montblanc/blob/53edf2ba505e4b5b10ae89e187c4f11d1e7072db/montblanc/tensorflow/rime_ops/b_sqrt_op_gpu.h#L126).
3. Python variable setup code is [here](https://github.com/ska-sa/montblanc/blob/53edf2ba505e4b5b10ae89e187c4f11d1e7072db/montblanc/tensorflow/rime_ops/test_b_sqrt.py#L131-L139)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify that one or more of the inputs to (or outputs from) a TensorFlow `OpKernel` are in "host memory", which allows you to access the value in the `Compute()` method. To do this you would modify your `REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER()` call to add a `.HostMemory("ref_freq")` instruction:

```
REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(
    Name("RimeBSqrt")
    .Device(tensorflow::DEVICE_GPU)
    .TypeConstraint<float>("FT")
    .TypeConstraint<tensorflow::complex64>("CT")
    .HostMemory("ref_freq"),
    RimeBSqrt<tensorflow::GPUDevice, float, tensorflow::complex64>);
```

Comment: Thanks! Does the HostMemory instruction also prevent the transfer of ref_freq to the GPU?

Comment: The HostMemory instruction will prevent it being copied automatically by the runtime. I'm by no means a CUDA expert, but I think you would modify the `OpKernel` to extract the `float` value from the tensor, and pass it as a `float` argument to the CUDA kernel (like you do for the `int` arguments [here](https://github.com/ska-sa/montblanc/blob/53edf2ba505e4b5b10ae89e187c4f11d1e7072db/montblanc/tensorflow/rime_ops/b_sqrt_op_gpu.h#L71)).

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: damn tensorflow, is this the only way to extract a scalar value to a regular float variable to be used in other computations?