# Device-agnostic way to read from a tensor?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, eigen3

I am writing a custom TensorFlow op that needs to be able to read the current value of a tensor within the OpKernel Compute() implementation in order to decide how to proceed. Eigen-unsupported's [`TensorMap` template](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/TensorMap_8h_source.html) (used by the `tensorflow::TTypes` typedefs) provides multiple overloads of the function call operator which I can use when the op is running on the host. In fact, the "[Adding a New Op](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op)" tutorial sample code uses the function call operator overloads to assign values into a tensor.

The problem is that when the op is running on a GPU, calling the function call operator overloads results in a segfault. This is because the function call operator overloads dereference an `m_data` member pointer, but this is a device pointer when the tensor resides on the GPU. Also, unlike [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37329661/196844), I don't think that I could use HostMemory() because the tensor is a temporary and is used by the GPU code.

I am currently calling cudaMemcpy() to copy device memory to host, but I would like to use a device-agnostic way to read from device memory—whether the device is `Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice`, `Eigen::GpuDevice`, or something else—because I would then be able to use the same eigen code, but compiled for each supported device (the "functor" approach).

I noticed the TensorBase::eval() method, but I am unsure whether this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the Eigen *Device types have a memcpyDeviceToHost() member. The implementations for `DefaultDevice` and `ThreadPoolDevice` call memcpy(). The implementation for `GpuDevice` calls cudaMemcpyAsync().

One issue is that `SyclDevice`'s memcpyDeviceToHost() has a different signature and different semantics; whereas `DefaultDevice`, `ThreadPoolDevice`, and `GpuDevice` have:

```
void memcpyDeviceToHost(void* dst, const void* src, size_t n) const
```

.. which copy `n` *bytes*, `SyclDevice` has:

```
void memcpyDeviceToHost(void* dst, const T* src, size_t n) const
```

.. which copies `n` *`T` objects*.

To avoid potential issues, it is probably best to static cast the `src` device pointer to `const void*` so that you'll get a compilation error when the device type is `SyclDevice`, pinpointing code that needs to be specialized for the different semantics of SyclDevice::memcpyDeviceToHost().